# "Найдут ли потом меня истекающим кровью?"

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Предложение выше написано в книге, которую перевели на русский. В данном случае причастный оборот после определяемого слова действительно не обособляется запятой или это вовсе не причастный оборот?

Answer (score 5):

Из Розенталя (Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. § 18. Обособленные определения ->   Согласованные определения, примечание 3 к п.10): ***Не обособляется*** определение при личном местоимении, если оно не согласовано с местоимением в падеже:

> Я вижу *его склонившимся* над чертёжной доской.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109

Судя по контексту (мальчик думает, что будет дальше: его *найдут избитым* или убежавший парнишка всё-таки обратится за подмогой), это наш случай.

Comment: Это единственно правильный ответ

Comment: По контексту там ничего ещё не случилось, просто злодеи хотят отнять велосипед, а лирический герой фантазирует, чем это может закончиться ("умрёт ли он, стрелой пронзённый"). https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=Zno3DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT75&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=grE-mSSHu9&sig=ACfU3U1gfwuUEvLrAOKAtla2-O3SIP1pwA&w=1280

Answer (score 3):

Да, это причастный оборот, который здесь не обособляется после определяемого слова, так как является **дуплексивом** (членом предложения с двунаправленной связью).

Он связан  с местоимением меня (согласование в роде и числе),  а глагол задает ему Т.п. Дуплексивы  могут не обособляться в безударной позиции, в отличие от других определительных оборотов, стоящих после определяемого слова.

Эта тема рассмотрена у Розенталя (там же приводятся сходные конструкции без обособления, п. 10).http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

Comment: А почему "Нет, так не говорят, предложение нужно исправить"?: Мы же весь текст не видим. Может,смысл здесь как раз не в том, что найдут или не найдут, а каким найдут. Это  и есть 3 случай в Вашем ответе -связь и с глаголом-сказуемым — нашли истекающим кровью (нашли раненым), и с местоимением — согласование в роде и числе. С остальным согласна.

Comment: Это же перевод какого-то произведения, мы его содержания не знаем, но такое понимание тоже возможно. Автора только пунктуация заинтересовала.

Comment: Что ж, понятно. У нас разные взгляды на этот ресурс. Я в первую очередь отвечаю автору, пытаюсь разрешить его сомнения, приводя своё мнение, подтверждая его источником знаний, а уже потом отвечаю на комментарии других членов сообщества, если их заинтересовало, а Вы, получается, отвечаете сразу всем, читая курс лекций. Что ж, каждому своё.

Comment: @Sharon Из Вашего ответа: _Дуплексивы могут не обособляться в безударной позиции находится..._ Мне кажется, что здесь надо внести поправку.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, исправила. Да только этому ответу вряд ли что-либо  поможет, если только слово "дуплексив" вычеркнуть.

Comment: Да пусть будет дуплексив — общую характеристику Вы ведь дали. Ищущий да разберется.