# Обособление определения, не согласованного с личным местоимением

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Дано предложение:

*Позже я встретил его, **уже постаревшим**, на улице.*

Как обособляются определения? Конечно, **по правилам Розенталя**. А вот и правило: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108  (п. 10, примечание 4).

Примечание. **Не обособляется** определение при личном местоимении:

3) если определение **не согласовано с местоимением в падеже**: *Я вижу **его склонившимся** над чертёжной доской* (связь и с глаголом-сказуемым — вижу склонившимся, и с местоимением — согласование в роде и числе);

Итак, по правилам оборот не должен обособляться. Или должен? Может быть, правило имеет **ограничения**, но ведь об этом ничего не говорится.

Как же решить эту задачу?

Кстати, опыт подобных решений  **на нашем ресурсе** имеется, но как-то он мне не очень помог. ["Найдут ли потом меня истекающим кровью?"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457596/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E/457597#457597)

Comment: В правилах говорится о тесной связи с глаголам. Определение следует сразу после глагола. В вашем случае, на мой взгляд, связь слабее, благодаря наречию уже.

Comment: Серж, мне кажется, что  на обособление здесь прежде всего влияет структура предложения и позиция оборота (он как бы не вписывается в это предложение). Сравнить: Позже я встретил его на улице уже совсем постаревшим. Здесь обособление не требуется.

Comment: И позиция тоже имеет значение. Согласен!

Comment: Sharon, хочу задать вам вопрос, не связанный с вашим вопросом. Если вы не против, скажите, куда вам написать?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, словосочетание обособляется, потому что это уточнение: не такого, каким я его знал, а постаревшего, изменившегося, почти другого человека. (Но это, конечно, от контекста зависит.)

> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения. <...>
>
> 4. Уточняющие определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста и т. д.: *Вошла молодая, лет семнадцати, девушка (Купр.)*

Поэтому (без контекста) кажется, что с тире будет тот же смысл:

> Позже я встретил его — уже постаревшим — на улице.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я тоже так думаю. Здесь автор  дает дополнительную информацию к основной теме, поэтому  обособляет определение.  Но в вопросе речь шла  о правильности формального решения задачи: никогда не обособляем, если нет согласования в падеже. В действительности же мы можем как обособлять, так и не обособлять, всё зависит от смысла.

Comment: Но если это уточнение, то вопрос согласования автоматически отпадает. Иначе говоря, то правило действует, но в этом случае применяется другое.

Comment: Я бы сказала так: для обособления оборотов, отнесенных к личному местоимению, действуют разные правила в зависимости от падежа. Для формы И.п. это  обязательное  формальное обособление (кроме сказуемого), а для Т.п. возможен авторский выбор по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

Если автор настаивает на рассогласованном падеже, то обособления быть не должно, согласно примечанию в правилах. Такой падеж соответствует усиленному акценту на возрасте, например в контексте встречи тренера с бывшим подопечным (мол, хотелось бы с ним ещё поработать, да поздно). Если же определение выполняет функцию малозначительного уточнения (встретил друга, он к тому времени постарел), то нужно изменить не только интонацию с пунктуацией, а и падеж (на согласованный), иначе заметен будет "авторский" стилистический изъян. Я не вижу оснований оговаривать в правилах новые исключения или послабления.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Собственно говоря, речь шла не о конкретном предложении, а о том, можно ли  обособлять несогласованный оборот. Допустим, я хочу придать ему уточняющее значение, разве это запрещается? И хочу оставить Т.падеж, потому что он, как известно, обозначает меняющийся во времени признак, а это как раз то, что мне нужно. Что у нас, правила главнее грамматики и смысла? В чем тут стилистический изъян?  Некоторый изъян я вижу в правилах, но правила не могут охватить все частные случаи.  Розенталь и так после каждого правила делает приписки, что нельзя всё понимать абсолютно.

Comment: И об этом же говорит во вступительной статье: "Если в области орфографии желательна и необходима полная унификация, то к пунктуации это требование неприменимо.Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает формальный подход к соблюдению правил.

Comment: На мой взгляд, обособление в этом примере привело бы не просто к "авторскому" расхождению с правилом, а к противоречию между между интонацией (пауза в случае "встретил его как**им**, в каком состоянии" неестественна) и пунктуацией. Поэтому нет смысла отдельно дозволять такое исключение. В этом примере я бы (наряду с обособлением) изменил падеж.

Answer (score 0):

Логическое ударение должно падать на слово "*постаревшим*" (так звучит):
*Позже я встретил его уже постарЕвшим на улице.* || Тогда получается, что он постарел на улице. Неверный смысл.

С запятыми получается добавочная информация (ударения другие). Не особо удачный формат (но возможно, что автор именно это и задумывал), зато нет двусмысленности:
*Позже я встрЕтил его, уже постаревшим, на улице.*
То есть несогласованный оборот может обособляться, если по задумке автора он является уточняющим или несёт дополнительную информацию, как и любые другие обороты. Причиной может быть то, что необходимо ударение на слове до оборота, тогда он автоматически становится вспомогательным. Ещё причиной может быть то, что некоторые элементы предложение из-за наличия оборота как бы выпадают из структуры (плохая читаемость). Эти два фактора можно наблюдать в данном примере. Но второй, по всей видимости, является следствием первого.

"*На улице*" лучше переставить, тогда будет хорошо читаться и двусмысленности не будет:
*Позже я встретил его на улице уже постарЕвшим.*

Ещё можно выделить "*на улице*" как добавочную информацию:
*Позже я встретил его уже постаревшим, на улице.*

Comment: oleedd, когда я читаю ваши ответы, то почему-то вспоминаю рассказ Чехова "Хамелеон". Вот не надо ничего менять и  портить мое предложение..  Оборот занимает именно такое место, где его нельзя не обособить.  "Он как-то незаметно исчез...   Позже я встретил его, уже постаревшим, на улице. Как я обрадовался!" Вот и скажите прямо: будете нарушать правило и обособлять или правило вам всего дороже?

Comment: Так вы тоже часто переделываете предложения из вопросов, если они кажутся некорректными. И мне предлагали... И бывает, не рассматриваете оригинальный "неверный" вариант. Обособить можно, если нужно ударение на слово "встретил". Судя по контексту, так и задумано. Смысл такой: *позже встретил его, но уже устаревшим*. Да и обрадовался, что встретил, а что постаревший - то уже второстепенно. Правила мне не дороже всего. Я их анализирую насквозь, чтобы правильно понимать и применять. Мне важен здравый смысл и звучание.

Comment: Тогда напишите ответ, который я хочу услышать: Несогласованный оборот может обособляться, если он имеет уточняющее значение и занимает удобную для обособления позицию. Или что-нибудь в этом роде. И будет вам счастье и благодарность лично от меня.

Comment: Так это и само собой разумелось во втором абзаце. Хорошо, добавлю это.

Comment: Добавьте и не забудьте привести предложение с обособленным оборотом и безо всяких изменений.

Comment: Так оно имеется во втором абзаце. Или что-то другое нужно?

Comment: Точно, есть. Ничего другого не нужно.

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать второй ответ с одним вариантом предложения. Позже я встретил его, уже постаревшим, на улице. Вы будете обособлять этот оборот или нет?  И укажите причину. Не надо приводить другие варианты.

Comment: Скопировать второй абзац в новый ответ? Это не мой стиль разговора, чтобы так составить предложение. Тут нужно учитывать контекст. А именно: что важно автору - то, что встретил, или то, что человек уже постарел. Здесь нельзя указать единственно верный вариант. Но структура способствует первому (иначе двусмысленность и плохая читаемость - это и есть причина).

Comment: Вы отвечаете на конкретный вопрос: Нужно ли обособлять оборот в заданном предложении.  В своем ответе вы приводите предложение с обособленным или необособленным оборотом и объясняете ваш выбор.  Это основная часть  ответа. При ее отсутствии ответ вообще нужно считать НЕКОРРЕКТНЫМ.  Вы это понимаете? А дальше (в примечаниях) можете рассказывать любые истории.

Comment: Я же сказал, что желательно, раз двусмысленность и плохая читаемость. Нужно обособлять - это когда второй вариант ошибочный. Не думаю, что применение правил Розенталя здесь можно назвать ошибочным. Не особо удачным - другое дело.

Comment: oleedd , если имеет место двусмысленность и плохая читаемость, то напишите, что предложение в таком виде стилистически некорректно и требуется редактирование. На этом мы с вами расстанемся, потому что я его считаю стилистически корректным, правка здесь не нужна.

Comment: "*я его считаю стилистически корректным, правка здесь не нужна*" — я вас не пойму. Вы что считаете, что запятые лучше не ставить, раз всё в порядке?

Comment: Предложение стилистически корректное, в нем нет никакой двусмысленности, оборот обособляется. Такие обороты могут  обособляться или  не обособляться. При обособлении оборот имеет значение уточнения и находится в позиции, удобной для обособления. Позже я встрЕтил его, уже постарЕвшим, на улИце. Это мой ответ.

Comment: Так да. Я говорю про двусмысленность (*постарел на улице*), если **не обособить**.